# MS Access 2007 add logo to all forms

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am wanting to add a logo to all my forms/reports etc.  I want to either store the image once in the database, even in the front end is okay, or I want to access a picture on the network/local computer.  I really don't care.  I can store a location in a table, and use a dlookup call as the control source in a picture control, and it works, but there is a noticeable delay from when the form opens and when the picture actually appears.  If I paste the picture in to every place, it works great!  But if I want to change the logo, I must open all my forms/reports and change every single one....  there has to be a faster way to change out my logo pictures and still get them to load instantaneously.  Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use vba perhaps.  Create a global variable in a module to link to a file location.  You could then use an image control on each form and set the source to the file location stored in your variable on the open event..  That way you would only ever change the value of the global.

Your code might look like this in each form:-

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Image0.Picture = yourGlobalFileLocationVariable
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts!  I always have trouble getting public variables to work, but I can see that this does work.  I defined a TempVar in my first form, set it to the file path, and just use that in all other forms.  They load WAY faster than they used to, so that is great!  If I put just...

    `Option Compare Database
    Public MyLogo as String
    MyLogo = "C:\MyLogo.jpg"`

I get a 'Invalid Outside Procedure' error with error highlighting the second line.  How can I get around this?  I have never been able to figure it out!!

Comment: Create a new standard module and declare your global variable in that, not in the form.  That should fix the problem, and should allow the variable to be accessed by the rest of your application.

Comment: The code I pasted in my first comment above is all I had in a stand alone module.  that is when I was getting that error.  Any other advice?